# How to change the generated .py file by SWIG in cmake?

Tags: python, cmake, swig

We can use **EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH** to something like **${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}**/bin. How to set the output path for a generated python module by SWIG.

ex, got the following CMakeLists.txt

```
FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG)
IF(SWIG_FOUND) 
FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
IF(PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)

INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND python -c "import sys;print"%s.%s"%sys.version_info[0:2]" OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_VERSION OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)


INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(partio.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(partio.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(partio python partio.i)
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(partio ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} ${ZLIB_LIBRARY} partio)

SET(PYTHON_DEST "lib64/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/site-packages" )
INSTALL(TARGETS _partio DESTINATION ${PYTHON_DEST})
INSTALL(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${outdir}/src/py/partio.py  DESTINATION ${PYTHON_DEST})

ENDIF(PYTHONLIBS_FOUND)
ENDIF(SWIG_FOUND)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need the "IF" guards; you should be able to add the "REQUIRED" argument to find_package, e.g. "find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [CMake 2.8 docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html):

> Another special variable is
>   CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR, it allows one to
>   specify where to write all the swig
>   generated module (swig -outdir option)

So, for example:

```
set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not versed with CMAKE, however I know you can set the output path of SWIG using a command line option to the SWIG executable:

```
swig.exe -outdir /path/I/want
```

Perhaps the line above that reads **SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")**

You can put in the parenthesis the required command line option?